# Localizable.Strings not picked up on iOS command line build

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

We have a command-line build script that creates our IPA automatically every day and it was working well until we added Localization.

For some reason the command-line build is not picking up Localizable.strings. If the project is built through Xcode, everything works correctly.

We are passing the clean flag through in the build, and I've tried emptying derived data and running Project > Clean from within xcode before running the build, but it still doesn't work.

The only thing I can think of, from looking at other questions on here, is that we have some other common projects that are included into the workspace, and they have Localizable.strings files themselves, so maybe this is causing a conflict? But if it were, it seems to me the manual Xcode build would also have the conflict.

Is there a step I am missing in the command-line build anyone can think of?

```
xcodebuild -workspace Project_Name.xcworkspace -sdk "iphoneos6.1" -scheme Project_Name CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$DISTRIBUTION_CERTIFICATE" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISONNING_PROFILE}" clean
xcodebuild -workspace Project_Name.xcworkspace -sdk "iphoneos6.1" -scheme Project_Name CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$DISTRIBUTION_CERTIFICATE" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISONNING_PROFILE}" archive
xcodebuild -workspace Project_Name.xcworkspace -sdk "iphoneos6.1" -scheme Project_Name CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$DISTRIBUTION_CERTIFICATE" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISONNING_PROFILE}" -configuration release

/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/Project_Name.app" -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/Project_Name.ipa" --sign "$DISTRIBUTION_CERTIFICATE" --embed "${PROVISONNING_PROFILE}"
```

Comment: Please post code from the script you are using.

Comment: @dmur ok just added relevant build script lines.